# Does the Chinese Government have any open satellite imagery?

Tags: images, china, aerial-photography, space, satellite

I'm looking for online data from Chinese satellites. I see them make the news frequently but is any of this public?

Answer (score 0):

Good Question but keep it in mind there might be censorship for any Chinese people to release it in the public.

You might want to contact anyone at any universities there if you know how to speak or write in Chinese.

For any specific area you are looking for in China.

https://gisgeography.com/free-satellite-imagery-data-list/